# How to access an object property which contains :: (colons) in its name

Tags: php, json, variables, properties

So this might be a simple question but not one I can find an answer for I have a variable that looks at a standard class object and stores the value from the various field names. Unfortunately, one of my fields is called [JOB::c_job_id].  If I use this in my variable

```
$jobid = ($json_data_single->response->data[0]->fieldData->JOB::c_job_id);
```

then it thinks the `::` is a Scope Resolution Operator(::) but I just want to retrieve the data from the field, how can I do this?

Comment: Can't you rename the field?

Comment: unfortunately not, I don't have access to the database and I am pulling the information via API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no way for you to rename that very unfortunately named key in the JSON, you can take one of the following approaches:

```php
$json = '{"JOB::c_job_id": 453}';

$decodedAsObject = json_decode($json);
var_dump($decodedAsObject->{'JOB::c_job_id'});

$decodedAsArray = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($decodedAsArray['JOB::c_job_id']);
```

The first one requires you to encase the property name in `{}` to make it be interpreted literally. The other is a bit more straightforward, because when you decode as an array, array keys are simple strings and there is no trouble when they contain characters or character sequences that can otherwise be interpreted as having special meaning for execution.

Live test available [here](https://3v4l.org/LvJoR).

Comment: Thankyou for this, i know what an unfortunate named key, it has something to do with how the app links tables thats why they get called (table1)::(field). I used the first method of encapsulating within {} but its good to know both.